# Escape special JSON characters on Razor page so that JSON.parse can be used with a date reviver

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, json.net

I’m using Asp.Net Core 3.1 MVC and am trying to serialize a model on a Razor page, but I need it to be encoded so that it will work with JSON.parse so that I can use a date reviver to convert date strings to date objects. Json.Serialize writes out the json in a way that it can be used without JSON.parse, so if you wrap it in single quotes to make it a string, special characters are not properly escaped and JSON.parse throws errors when characters such as "\" are encountered.

```
// Model definition { "myField": "abc\\def" }
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = '@Json.Serialize(Model)',
       json = JSON.parse(data, myDateReviver);
</script>
```

I found a workaround, that I'd like to avoid using if at all possible.

```
// Model definition { "myField": "abc\\def" }
<script type="text/javascript">
   var data = JSON.stringify(@Json.Serialize(Model)),
       json = JSON.parse(data, myDateReviver);
</script>
```

Is there a proper way to string encode the result of @Json.Serialize so that  it's compatible with JSON.parse?

Comment: `Json.parse` need a(Json) string ,and `@Json.Serialize(Model)` returns a new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent containing the serialized JSON.So you need to  use `JSON.stringify` before use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: It's only IHtmlContent on the server, the problem is that @Json.Serialize doesn't have an option to encode the output to be used as a string; I'm looking for a way to properly encode the string when the server writes it to the page, using stringify just to do parse is a hack...

Comment: Do you mean you want a function like escape()?The escape() function computes a new string in which certain characters have been replaced by a hexadecimal escape sequence.

Comment: Where is the escape function you are referring to and does have a signature that takes IHtmlContent?

Comment: You can refer to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape)

Comment: "Although escape() is not strictly deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is defined in Annex B of the ECMA-262 standard, whose introduction states..Programmers should not use or..."

I can't believe they removed the ability to encode serialized JSON...